# REST API support and naming for POSTing data as json or file upload

Tags: c#, api, rest, .net-6.0, conventions

I have a REST API controller supporting the following:

```
IActionResult PostRows([FromBody] Rows[] body)
```

> POST /api/v1/rows
>
> with a JSON body, e.g. `[{ id: 1}, { id: 2}]`

---

I also just added a REST API endpoint supporting the following:

```
[Route("csv")]
IActionResult PostRows2([FromForm] IFormFile csv)
```

> POST /api/v1/rows/csv
>
> Content-Type:multipart/form-data

accepting a CSV file, e.g.:

```
id
1
2
```

However I don't like the endpoint naming with the `/csv` appended.

Is there a way to have a single POST endpoint, supporting both modes? If not, what is the best naming convention when having to post the same data in different formats?

Comment: I think it is not possible because you will have problem with multiple endpoint match. Also i suggest naming /import instead of file type.

Comment: You should have a single post endpoint if every data is example in string or text, and when you receive the string you check with ex. regex, to guest the string type, ex. regex: /^{*}$/ checks the string wheter starts and ends with {}, then you convert to json, if not json then use the string data as csv

Comment: One possible way is, You can do something like `public IActionResult PostRows([FromBody] Rows[] body, [FromForm] IFormFile csv)` this. Inside method you can check null condition of either of them ex: `if body != null` then process for rows and if `csv != null` then process for csv.

Comment: @NaimishMakwana Hi thanks, I tried it but somehow got an exception so I suppose this is not supported